# C - _IOLBF custom buffer does not load a single line

Tags: c, file, buffer

I have a text file that contains 20 rows and 30 columns of integers.
Through a C program I want to create a custom buffer and load only the first line of the file on it.

Why does my buffer contain the whole file and not just the first line, if I set the buffer mode in _IOLBF with setvbuf?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
       char buffer[1024];
       FILE * fp;
       int val;

       fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

       setvbuf(fp, buffer, _IOLBF, 1024);
       fscanf(fp, "%d", &val);

       printf("Contenuto del buffer: ");
       for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
              printf("%c\n", buffer[i]);

       return 0;
}
```

Does it have anything to do with this?

> According to this Microsoft documentation:
>
> > _IOLBF: For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as _IOFBF - Full Buffering.

[Setting C program to line buffer won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653603/setting-c-program-to-line-buffer-wont-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are confusing what `setvbuf` is doing. Generally it is only used in the way you are attempting to use it on *output* streams. Setting an input stream to line buffered has no impact whatsoever on what will be read from it, e.g. it does not force a read to stop at the end of a line. That is what line-oriented input functions, such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline` are useful for.

If you want to read the first row of integers, either limit your loop to read `30` integers, or if you want to read the line as text into buffer, then call `fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);` and buffer will then contain the first line from the file.